# Fontawesome в псевдоклассе

Tags: html, css, fontawesome

Как можно засунуть иконку с Fontawesome в псевдокласс. 
Пример кода:

```
<form>
  <input type='text' name='name' value='' placeholder='Имя'>
  <input type='text' name='tel' value='' placeholder='Телефон'>
  <textarea name='message' placeholder='содержание'></textarea>
  <input type='submit' name='send' value='Отправить'>
</form>
```

Я хочу, применть его к input.

Comment: Я дал ответ на данный вопрос, автор ответ не принимает и никак дополнительно не комментирует, поэтому ставлю минус вопросу.

Answer (score 1):

Насколько мне известно, к **input** стандартными способами не добавить.
Используйте обертку.
Если есть лучшие решения, рад буду узнать.

```css
body {
  text-align: center;
  background-color: #EFF1F5;
}

label.wrapper_input {
  display: block;
}
label.wrapper_input:after {
  font-family: fontawesome;
  font-size: 18px;
  position: relative;
  right: 24px;
  color: deepskyblue;
}
label.wrapper_input.input_name:after {
  content: '\f007';
}
label.wrapper_input.input_phone:after {
  content: '\f095 ';
}

label.wrapper_input_submit:after {
  font-family: fontawesome;
  content: '\f105';
  font-size: 15px;
  position: relative;
  right: 17px;
  color: #fff;
}

input[type="submit"] {
  background-color: deepskyblue;
  color: #fff;
  border-radius: 5px;
  padding: 10px 20px 10px 10px;
  margin-top: 10px;
  font-weight: 600;
}

input[type="text"] {
  background-color: #fff;
  border-radius: 5px;
  padding: 10px 30px 10px 10px;
  margin-top: 5px;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>


<form action="#">
  <label class="wrapper_input input_name">
    <input type='text' name='name' value='' placeholder='Имя'>
  </label>

  <label class="wrapper_input input_phone">
    <input type='text' name='tel' value='' placeholder='Телефон'>
  </label>

  <label class="wrapper_input_submit">
    <input type="submit" />
  </label>
</form>
```

Comment: думаю было бы лучше использовать `label`, заодно и полезно будет

Comment: Заменил на `label`. Как сейчас по вашему?